# Polymer: Call a behavior's property function in elements property values?

Tags: properties, polymer, polymer-1.0, behavior

Recently I looked up Polymers `app-localize-behavior` and I saw they typed the `localize()` method as `Function` (see on [GitHub](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-localize-behavior/blob/master/app-localize-behavior.html#L196)):

excerpt from `app-localize-behavior.html`:

```
localize: {
  type: Function,
  computed: '__computeLocalize(language, resources, formats)'
},
```

This method works perfectly fine in data-bindings, like `<div>{{localize('welcome')}}</div>`, but how can I call this method from my elements properties? I try to do something like:

excerpt from `my-element.html`:

```
properties: {
    _pageTitle: {
      type: String,
      value: this.localize('welcome')
    }
}
```

But when I try this, I get a `Uncaught TypeError: this.localize is not a function`. Even in my `ready` method I need to call `this.localize` asynchronously as otherwise it isn't defined, too.

How could I solve that problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [computed property](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#computed-properties) that invokes `localize(...)`:

```
properties: {
  _pageTitle: {
    computed: 'localize("welcome")'
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/KXJmXo?editors=1010)

Comment: Awesome. But: there are other properties I need to localize, but those aren't strings but Objects. Any chance to compute that? They should return a JSON Object